# Combining memory cache (like LruCache) and WeakReference

Tags: java, caching, memory, memcached

What do you think about storing weak references in memory cache to objects that are outside of cache size?
Does it worth it?
Can it be a new memory cache pattern? =)
Or I'm missing some libraries that already done it?

This way we can access objects by id even if they are removed from memory cache itself (in case we don't want to have big memory cache).

MemCache source is here: http://pastebin.com/N3iuJgNb

Sample code:

```
Test before1 = new Test("1");                   // Strong reference in code, weak reference in MemCache
Test before2 = new Test("2");                   // Weak reference in MemCache
Test before3 = new Test("3");                   // Strong reference in code and in MemCache
Test before4 = new Test("4");                   // Strong reference in MemCache

MemCache<Test> cache = new MemCache<Test>(2);   // At most two items are strongly referenced

cache.put(before1.id, before1);                 // Weak reference
cache.put(before2.id, before2);                 // Weak reference
cache.put(before3.id, before3);                 // Strong reference
cache.put(before4.id, before4);                 // Strong reference

before2 = null;
before4 = null;

System.gc();

try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Test after1 = cache.get("1");                   // LruCache will return null here
Test after2 = cache.get("2");
Test after3 = cache.get("3");
Test after4 = cache.get("4");

assert after1 == before1;
assert after2 == null;
assert after3 == before3;
assert after4 != null;

System.out.println("Success!!!");
```

Comment: There are 1001 simple memory caching libraries available for Java. There is a simple and effective one [built into Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). Best not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why `WeakReference` over `SoftReference`? That one has at least the intention to act a bit like a cache.

Comment: for caching we have strong references inside memcache. weak references are only to store objects that are referenced outside but doesn't fit to cache. this way they will be automatically removed after all references are gone.

Comment: Also I'm from Android world where SoftReference is more or less equals WeakReference =)